# How to interprete this で?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

This is an excerpt from my dialogue with my language partner. For some context, I basically asked her about the difference in について and は, since both can be translated to "Concerning X".

The sentence in question:
「ついて」の使い方ですが、後ろに名詞が来るか、動詞が来るかで少し違います。

My attempt at translation:
"About the usage of 「ついて」, it varies a bit based on wether a noun or a verb comes at the rear."

Here, I basically interpreted で as a marker for a "means" or better a "cause", like in 事故 で 電車が止まりました。
However, I also learned in my textbook that to express something like "depending on X, it is A or B", a construction with によって is used, like this: 好きな食べ物は人によって違います。

That's why I wanted to ask wether my interpretation of で in the sentence above is legit or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is perfect in every sense.

Yes, this 「で」 has the same meaning as 「によって」.
So you can rephrase the original sentence as 「後ろに名詞が来るか、動詞が来るか**によって**少し違います」.

This meaning of 「で」 can formally be expressed as "cause", though I feel like 「で」 has sometimes a meaning like "depending on", for example in 「この店の売り物は曜日**で**変わる」.